# Animating a property of a custom Shape in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an `Arc`/`Circle` shape for which I am updating the end angle in a view.

I defined `animatableData` for the shape to animate it, however there is no animation happening in the view.

How can I fix this? I want to reach to same result that we get from `trim`, but without using that modifier.

This is my current code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var endAngle: Angle = Angle()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button("add") { endAngle += Angle(degrees: 30.0) }.padding()
        
        CircleShape(lineWidth: 10, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0.0), endAngle: endAngle)
            .stroke(Color.green, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round))
            .animation(.default, value: endAngle)
 
    }
    
}

struct CircleShape: Shape {
    
    let lineWidth: CGFloat
    var startAngle: Angle
    var endAngle: Angle
    
    var animatableData: Angle {
        get { endAngle }
        set { self.endAngle = newValue }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {

        return Path { path in
            
            let radius: CGFloat = (min(rect.maxX, rect.maxY) - lineWidth)/2.0
            
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY),
                        radius: radius,
                        startAngle: startAngle,
                        endAngle: endAngle,
                        clockwise: false)
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I think this is because `Angle` does not conform to `VectorArithmetic`

Comment: If `trim` is giving you what you want, why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: Because it is a ready api and I don’t know how apple implemented the goal! With my way I have control on all process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cedric's solution above works because it substitutes `Angle` for a value that implements `VectorArithmetic`.  Another solution is to add an extension that makes `Angle` itself support `VectorArithmetic`.  Here's a Playground that does that:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

extension Angle : AdditiveArithmetic {
    public static var zero: Angle {
        get { return Angle(degrees: 0)}
    }

    public static func + (lhs: Angle, rhs: Angle) -> Angle {
        return Angle(degrees: fmod(lhs.degrees + rhs.degrees, 360.0))
    }

    public static func += (lhs: inout Angle, rhs: Angle) {
        lhs.degrees = (lhs + rhs).degrees
    }

    public static func - (lhs: Angle, rhs: Angle) -> Angle {
        return Angle(degrees: fmod(lhs.degrees - rhs.degrees, 360.0))
    }

    public static func -= (lhs: inout Angle, rhs: Angle) {
        lhs.degrees = (lhs - rhs).degrees
    }
}

extension Angle : VectorArithmetic {
    public mutating func scale(by rhs: Double) {
        self.degrees = fmod(self.degrees * rhs, 360.0)
    }

    public var magnitudeSquared: Double {
        return self.degrees * self.degrees
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var endAngle: Angle = Angle()

    var body: some View {
        Button("add") { endAngle += Angle(degrees: 30.0) }.padding()

        CircleShape(lineWidth: 10, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0.0), endAngle: endAngle)
            .stroke(Color.green, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round))
            .animation(.default, value: endAngle)
    }
}

struct CircleShape: Shape {
    let lineWidth: CGFloat
    var startAngle: Angle
    var endAngle: Angle

    var animatableData: Angle {
        get { endAngle }
        set { self.endAngle = newValue }
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { path in

            let radius: CGFloat = (min(rect.maxX, rect.maxY) - lineWidth)/2.0

            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY),
                        radius: radius,
                        startAngle: startAngle,
                        endAngle: endAngle,
                        clockwise: false)

        }

    }
}

let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
hostingController.view.bounds = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 320,height: 480)
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = hostingController
```

Comment: Thanks, Your answer fit to question, I know that `Angle` does not conform to `VectorArithmetic` and I know also if we want make it to conform we should code for `scale` function and for computed value of `magnitudeSquared`, but I had no reference or sample to finish those! How could you find the needed code for there? Or how could I be lucky enough to find the missing code for them? in similar situations? or to conforming other protocols?

Comment: I have some formal education in Vector math and I implemented those functions based on the definitions implied by their names... Though now that I look at it, to be consistent with the rest of the implementation, `magnitudeSquared` should probably return `fmod(self.degrees * self.degrees, 360.0)`

Comment: Why doesn't `Angle` conform to `AdditiveArithmetic`? I would've assumed that it did

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the use of `Angle`.

One of the simplest solutions is to use the `CGFloat` type which conforms `VectorArithmetic`.

So changing `Angle` to `CGFloat`, your code would look like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var endAngle: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Button("add") { endAngle += 30.0 }.padding()
            
            CircleShape(lineWidth: 10, startAngle: 0, endAngle: endAngle)
                .stroke(Color.green, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round))
                .animation(.default, value: endAngle)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct CircleShape: Shape {
    
    let lineWidth: CGFloat
    var startAngle: CGFloat
    var endAngle: CGFloat
    
    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { endAngle }
        set { endAngle = newValue }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {

        return Path { path in
            
            let radius: CGFloat = (min(rect.maxX, rect.maxY) - lineWidth)/2.0
            
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY),
                        radius: radius,
                        startAngle:  Angle(degrees: startAngle),
                        endAngle: Angle(degrees: endAngle),
                        clockwise: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angle already Conforms to Animatable, so all you have to do is to modify your shape's animatableData property:

```
var animatableData: Angle.AnimatableData {
    get { endAngle.animatableData }
    set { endAngle.animatableData = newValue }
}
```

Bonus: if you want to animate both start and end angles:

```
var animatableData: AnimatablePair<Angle.AnimatableData, Angle.AnimatableData> {
    get { AnimatableData(startAngle.animatableData, endAngle.animatableData) }
    set { startAngle.animatableData = newValue.first; endAngle.animatableData = newValue.second }
}
```